# Call service after other service finishes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-observable

I have the following on an Angular's component:

```
notifier: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {

  this.authService.init();

  this.notifier = this.noteService.get().subscribe((note: Note) => { 

    if (note.code == 1) {
      this.authService.init();
    }

  });

}
```

After authService.init() ends getting data from the database I need to call:

```
this.noteService.send(2);
```

The `authService` is as follows:

```
export class AuthorizationService {

  private data$: Observable<Data[]>;

  init() {
    this.data$ = this.httpClient.get<Data[]>>(`auth/data`);
  }

}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Why not creating an instance of the second service and use it in the first service after finishing its logic or in ngOnDestroy() method, or you can do it with a simple variable which refers if the first service has done its job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to concatenate requests.

But first I recommend you to change your init() method in AuthorizationService like this:

```
export class AuthorizationService {

  private data$: Observable<Data[]>;

  init(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Data[]>>(`auth/data`);
  }

}
```

Then in your Component:

```
notifier: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.init().pipe(flatMap(() => this.noteService.send(2))).subscribe(
        () => {
           // Success of this.noteService.send(2)
        }
     );

  });

}
```